# Intuitive perspective on evolution of densities in dynamical systems

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems

I am trying to understand the intuitive derivation of the Frobenius-Perron (FP) operator in the monograph:

Lasota, Andrzej, and Michael C. Mackey. Chaos, fractals, and noise: stochastic aspects of dynamics. Vol. 97. Springer.

Specifically section 1.2. Assume we have a transformation $S :[0, 1] -> [0, 1]$ and pick a large number of $N$ initial states
$x^0_1, x^0_2,...,x^0_N$

Define an indicator function (or characteristic function) defined for a set $\Delta$ as
\begin{equation}
1_{\Delta}(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & if\,x\in\Delta\\
0 & if\,x\notin\Delta
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The we say that the function $f_o(x)$ is the density function for the initial states $x^0_1, x^0_2,...,x^0_N$  if for every (not too small) interval $\Delta_0 \subset [0, 1]$ we have

\begin{equation}
\int_{\Delta_o} f_o (u) du \approx \frac{1}{N} \Sigma_1 ^N 1_{\Delta_o}(x^0_j)
\end{equation}

My conceptual difficulty is the right hand side of the above should be 1.

Unless the interpretation is that the initial states $x^0_j$ could be out of the $\Delta_o$. Please advise on my understanding of the definition of density of states.
The text goes on to use this to give an intuitive derivation of the FP operator.